# How to log Http Request body in Spring MVC?

Tags: http, logging, spring-mvc, request

Just think it will be a useful feature for dev stage. Is it something I can configure or requires a bit coding? Thank you stackers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use: [spring-mvc-logger](https://github.com/isrsal/spring-mvc-logger)

Add to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.isrsal</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc-logger</artifactId>
    <version>0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Add to web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>loggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.github.isrsal.logging.LoggingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>loggingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Add to log4j.xml:

```
<logger name="com.github.isrsal.logging.LoggingFilter">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [`AbstractRequestLoggingFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.html) family of filters.

Aslo it may be convenient to use client-side tools for debugging, such as [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).